# How to refresh component faster when user presses F5

Tags: routes, components, angular7

I am using Angular 7. When the user needs to switch from one component to another then routing is working fast and fine. But when the user presses `F5` then the application takes much time to reload, approximately 40 seconds.

Can you please help to reduce this time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you run your Angular app in development mode (`ng serve`) or on a production server? In development mode, reloading might take some more time than on your built app because Angular uses a live server to deliver the app in JIT mode ("just in time") while the built app is finally compiled and delivered [AOT ("ahead of time")](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler).

40 seconds seems way too long for a web app to initialize. The thing is that on reloading, the server gets a new request and Angular has to re-initialize and perform the routing to the correct component. This can take some more time than the normal routing behavior which loads only the specific page content without having to reload the whole page.

Did you try reloading on several of your Angular pages? Are they all as slowly as 40 seconds or does the reload time depend on the page you reload?

Comment: Yes, i am running in development mode.

Comment: Do you use many services and / or plugins in your web app? Maybe you should think about lazy loading strategies in combination with routing (see https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules).